# How can I add a success message to my mail form code?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, plugins, phpmailer

I tried using echo but something's wrong in that echo area.
I got syntax errors and and an error saying unexpected token after`echo "Try again."`

```
<?php

add_action("admin_menu", "addMenu");
function addMenu()
{
  add_menu_page("smail", "smail", 4, "smail", "sMail" );
}

function sMail()
{
?>
  <h2> send mail</h2>




        <form method="post" action="">      

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = sanitize_email( $_POST['email_address'] );
$subject = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['subject'] );
$txt =  esc_textarea( $_POST['text'] );
$from = sanitize_email( $_POST['frommail'] );
$headers = "From:" . $from ;

if (mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers)){
   echo "Mail sent successfully.";
} else{
   echo "Try again.";
}

}
?>
            
        <label for="frommail">From </label>
            <input id="frommail" name="frommail" type="text" maxlength="255" />
        <label for="email_address">To </label>
        
            <input id="email_address" name="email_address" type="text" maxlength="255"/> 
        
        <label for="subject">Subject </label>
        
            <input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" maxlength="255" /> 
        
    
        <label for="text">Text </label>
        
            <textarea id="text" name="text" row="10"></textarea>
        
          <input value="submit" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">
        
        </form> 



<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't define functions like in your `sMail` function.
If you want to print out html content, use echo instead.

You also miss a `}` from end of file.

Also:

- If you want to use the current script for your action path, just leave out the action tag.

Here's your corrected code:

```php
<?php
add_action("admin_menu", "addMenu");
function addMenu()
{
    add_menu_page("smail", "smail", 4, "smail", "sMail");
}

function sMail()
{

    echo "  <h2> send mail</h2> ";

    echo " <form method='post' action=''>       ";

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $to = sanitize_email($_POST['email_address']);
        $subject = sanitize_text_field($_POST['subject']);
        $txt = esc_textarea($_POST['text']);
        $from = sanitize_email($_POST['frommail']);
        $headers = "From:" . $from;

        if (mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers))
        {
            echo "Mail sent successfully.";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Try again.";
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I want you to know that this is a part of a wordpress plugin I am working on.

Comment: Sorry, you forgot to highlight it.
Anyways, could you resolve the syntax error?